# I switched to intel integrated graphics and now I can't switch back to gpu

Tags: nvidia, graphics, gpu

so I switched to my intel integrated graphics on my acer nitro 5 laptop with a intel core i5 8300h and a gtx 1050 and now I can't switch it back to my gpu. I switched it using nvidia x server settings and after I switched it nvidia x server settings wouldn't open. I forgot to mention I have linux installed on my laptop. I tried uninstalling and installing nvidia x server settings again and I tried installing different drivers for nvidia and it won't work. I can't find the option to switch to my gpu in my bios and my friend said my gpu is fried. I only disabled it so I don't think there is anything wrong with the gpu but it isn't showing up in sudo lshw or lspci. im out of options. If I can reinstall linux and the problemis fixed I would do it but I would want to know for sure if it will work first. please be kind enough to help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a complete purge of all the Nvidia-related stuff first?

Try this line in a terminal first:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
```

then reinstall a compatible driver for your graphics card.

Comment: yes I tried that but I get an error msg saying Unable to locate package nvidia-bug-report.log.gz and when I try to install nvidia drivers with the command sudo apt-get install nvidia-370 it says unable to locate file

Comment: When you try to purge the Nvidia drivers it says a file is missing? Are you sure? Also, you might want to try using the graphical interface (Software & Updates, Additional drivers).